I write #include <stdio.h>,facing file not found
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (E:\code\c\test_4_17.cpp).C/C++(1696) cannot open source file "stdio.h". Please run the 'Select IntelliSense Configuration...' command to locate your system headers.C/C++(1696)
{ "configurations": [ { "name": "Win32", "includePath": [ "${workspaceFolder}/**" ], "defines": [ "_DEBUG", "UNICODE", "_UNICODE" ] } ], "version": 4 }
what can i  do to solve this question?I use windows 11 to code with visual studio code and delete vs install.is it the reason that lead to the problem,but it is well if i use Dev-c++ to code,which i write  #include<stdio.h>
